# Position first p in div higher than another p inside same div

Tags: html, css

I have this:

[image: image I have]

but my goal is to get this:

[image]

My code is:

```css
.bonus-div {
  width: 290px;
  height: 29px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
}

.bonus-div>p {
  display: inline;
  height: 29px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.bonus-div>p:last-child {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2ABD77;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bonus-div">
  <p>+$4</i>Bonus</p>
  <p>= $24.00</p>
</div>
```

So, how can I position first `p` inside this `div` to be little bit closer to top, and make it's position same as on the second picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) approach:

```css
.bonus-div {
  width: 290px;
  height: 29px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bonus-div>p {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.bonus-div>p:last-child {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2ABD77;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bonus-div">
  <p>+$4 Bonus</p>
  <p>= $24.00</p>
</div>
```

Or use `vertical-align`:

```css
.bonus-div {
  width: 290px;
  height: 29px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.bonus-div p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bonus-div>p {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.bonus-div>p:last-child {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2ABD77;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bonus-div">
  <p>+$4 Bonus</p>
  <p>= $24.00</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
.bonus-div {
  display : flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has many solutions. I will give you the easiest to implement.

**HTML**

```
<div class='bonus-div'>
    <p>+$4.00 Bonus</p>
    <p> = </p>
    <p>$24.00</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bonus-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bonus-div > p {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.bonus-div > p:last-child{
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #2ABD77;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

My solution uses the flexbox property. If you mind not supporting older browsers then do not use flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

add vertical-align:text-top; in css

```
<style type="text/css">
.bonus-div {
  width: 290px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#000;
}

.bonus-div > p {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.bonus-div > p:first-child{
    color: #2ABD77;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
.bonus-div > p:last-child{
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2ABD77;
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align:text-top;
}
</style>
<div class="bonus-div">
   <p>+$4</i>Bonus</p>
   <p>= $24.00</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table-like displaying to make sure every vertical alignement is made automatically no matter how you resize your font. I used `display: table` and its child properties `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` to perform this trick. I like those properties since they are nicely integrated now in most of browsers (check out [css display:table](https://caniuse.com/css-table/embed/) caniuse compatibility table).

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4odfwse2/

**CSS**

```
.bonus-div {
  width: 290px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#000;
}

.bonus-div-bonus, .bonus-div-total {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.bonus-div-bonus {
  color : #FFFFFF;
  text-align: right;
}

.bonus-div-total {
  color : #2ABD77;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align : left;
}

.bonus-div-table {
  display : table;
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
}

.bonus-div-row {
  display : table-row;
}

.bonus-div-cell {
  display : table-cell;
  vertical-align : middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bonus-div">
  <div class="bonus-div-table">
    <div class="bonus-div-row">
      <div class="bonus-div-cell bonus-div-bonus">
        +$4.00 Bonus
      </div>
      <div class="bonus-div-cell bonus-div-total">
        &nbsp;= $24.00
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```